GeoServer ECW problem
I know this topic have been brought up before, but with different situations.
I have been trying to configure geoserver to serve ecw extensions, following documentation and several other different instructions. I managed to get it working in my local computer with standalone geoserver instalation.
Now I need to perform the same task on a Windows Server instance which has geoserver running under Tomcat. Followed the same instructions, changing the packages to match GS version. I guess I set up all necessary environment variables (GDAL_DATA, GDAL_DRIVER_PATH and PATH pointing to the location of the packages I downloaded from gisinternals.com). Managed to make geoserver show additional extensions from gdal, except ECW.

One observation point is that in this server there is more than one GDAL instance, however, I already edit env variables to look only to gisinternals package. Another strange behavior is that when I run gdalinfo -- I get some DLLs missing.:
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\GDAL\bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.

GDAL 3.6.2, released 2023/01/02 

Those files exist and their path is specified in GDAL_DRIVER_PATH env variable.
gdalinfo --formats shows ECW. I can even run gdal_translate and transform ECW to another formats without problems. Is there any additional step for gisinternals package or I can only load and point to it in the variables?
GeoServer version: 2.23.2
GDAL (gisinternals) version: 3.6.2
I undestand that ECW is a paid format and the customer has agreed to license it, but in order to continue we need to test and check it's running.

check that user that is running the tomcat service can read the GDA dlls
